# jQuery Autocomplete not working via AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, api

I've incorporated the jQuery Autocomplete library from https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

On the server (Laravel) I'm formatting the response as follows:

```
Route::get('/api/v1/products', function() {
    foreach(App\Product::all() as $product) {
        $products[] = [
            'value' => $product->name,
            'data'  => $product->id
        ];
    }

    return response()->json($products)->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});
```

This produces the following response:

```
[
{
"value": "Test Product 1",
"data": 1
},
{
"value": "Skateboard",
"data": 23
},
{
"value": "Surfboard",
"data": 24
}
]
```

In order for the library to consume the data I use the following code:

```
jQuery('#product-search').autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: '/api/v1/products',
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            }
        });
```

Upon typing, the console returns this error:

[image]

I've already added the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header to make sure there are no CORS errors. Other than that I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

I've also made sure that the json response is in the correct format.

What am I missing?

Comment: html is dynamically genrated, I mean via ajax reponse?

Comment: @VasimVanzara I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: you have to determine if control is really exists?

Comment: for Access-Control-Allow-Origin you can use [this package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: What could the console message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the way you return the response. You simply return an array with the suggestion but, if you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/dist/jquery.autocomplete.js#L806), the plugin requires an object called `suggestions` like so:

```
{"suggestions": [{"value": "xxx", data: 1}, {"value": "xxx", data: 1} /* ... */]}
```

So you have to change your route from:

```
return response()->json($products)->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

to:

```
return response()->json(['suggestions' => $products])->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```